# How to make Post call using RxAlamofire pass json in post body

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, rx-swift, rxalamofire

I want to make a post call using **RxAlamofire** it provides **function** **requestJson** which requires **two parameters** **type get or post and url** but there is **no parameter to pass post json body** how to do that following is my code

```
 var components = URLComponents(string: url)!
    components.setQueryItems(with: param)
    let url = components.url!
    print("\(url)")

    RxAlamofire.requestJSON(.post, url)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (r, json) in
            if let jsonResult = JSON(json) as? JSON {
                if let cartResult = FoodCartResult(jsonResult) as? FoodCartResult {
                    self?.delegate?.showCart(cartresult: cartResult)
                }
            }

            }, onError: {  [weak self] (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self?.delegate?.onError()
            },onCompleted: {})
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the other parameters are included in the definition of requestJson, they just have default parameters. So you can safely say:

```
RxAlamofire.requestJSON(.post,
                        url,
                        parameters: ["param1": "value1"],
                        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                        headers: nil)
```